# Setting vertical margins on top and below align* environment

Tags: environments, margins, amsmath

I'm using the amsmath `align*` environment to format multi line formulas. Unfortunately, the environment adds a lot of margin before and below the formula. I [found](http://snipplr.com/view/29080/align-environment-without-margins/) only one solution to get rid of this margins, but I fear it is a little bit hacky:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
    \newenvironment{myalign*}{%
      \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}%
      \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{\abovedisplayskip}%
      \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
    }%
    {\endalign}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et
consequat erat, non malesuada tortor. Phasellus porta cursus risus, eu
rutrum ligula suscipit sed. Proin vestibulum malesuada lacinia.
\begin{myalign*}
x &= 4 \times 5 \\
y &= x
\end{myalign*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et
consequat erat, non malesuada tortor. Phasellus porta cursus risus, eu
rutrum ligula suscipit sed. Proin vestibulum malesuada lacinia.

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**: Also without the blank lines before and after the environment I get too much space. It works when I set both lengths to `0pt`.

Is there also another way to avoid the margins?

Comment: Avoid blank lines around `align*`, that's all.

Comment: @egreg Nope :-) that's not all. I tested it for my MWE and without the blank lines I have the margin!

Comment: The vertical space around the alignment is necessary for readability.

Comment: @egreg Agree when you use it in a plain text document. I use it in a different situation, so readability is fine for me ^^

Comment: Can you try and explain this different situation?

Comment: @egreg I use it in a figure environment that collects a set of artifacts, e.g., a gray text box, the formula, again a gray text box. There is no need for big margin to the gray boxes.

Comment: Probably `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$` is what you're looking for.

Comment: in this context, "margins" usually implies (to me, anyhow) the horizontal space on either side of a display.  please change the title to make it clear you mean the vertical space above and below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newenvironment{smashedalign}
 {\par$\!\aligned}
 {\endaligned$\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a.pdf}
\begin{smashedalign}
x &= 4 \times 5 \\
y &= x
\end{smashedalign}
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

No, don't set negative values for `\abovedisplayskip` that will cause the math to over-print the preceding paragraph.

The spurious white area is not vertical space added by `align` it is a blank horizontal line of a paragraph added by you by having a blank line before the display. This is not vertical space and is not dropped at the top of a page.

*Never* leave a blank line before display math environments.

If you delete the spurious blank lines in your input you get

[image]